# MYSQL nested queries in JPA NativeQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm trying to implement the Nested Subset algorithm to handle hierarchies in a relational database (MySQL).

Specifically I'm following this excellent guide at http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

The algorithm for insertion gives the following query to insert a new node and renumber all nodes:

```
SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM nested_category
WHERE name = 'TELEVISIONS';

UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;
UPDATE nested_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;

INSERT INTO nested_category(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('GAME CONSOLES', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);
```

I have tried to insert the above in a JPA Native Query as follows:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM nested_category
    WHERE name = 'TELEVISIONS';
    UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myRight;
    UPDATE nested_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;
    INSERT INTO nested_category(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('GAME CONSOLES', @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);");
query.getResultList();
```

But I get an **Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException**

Is there some way to modify the above query into an equivalent query or somehow let Native Query handle the above query?

I tried some nested subquery as follows:

```
UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > (SELECT rgt FROM nested_category WHERE name = 'TELEVISIONS');
```

But I get an **#1093 - You can't specify target table 'nested_category' for update in FROM clause**

apparently I can't update from a table from which I select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont' know if you want to solve the above in a single query but easiest way would be to split into 4 easy native queries.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT rgt FROM nested_category
    WHERE name = 'TELEVISIONS';");
List<Object> rightSiblings = query.getResultList();
for (Object sibling : rightSiblings)
            {
                Integer siblingId = (Integer) sibling;
                query = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >"+siblingId);
                query.executeUpdate();
            }
```

and then go on treating each query separately.